# QoS (quality of service) criteria in router for Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm looking for QoS criteria in order to lower priority of traffic while synchronizing big files. Ubuntu One uses 443 port which cannot be good criteria because it is common for all https traffic. Destination IP is also does not seems to work because Ubuntu One uses range of IP's.
Any ideas will be appreciated,
Thanks,
yb.

Comment: This is a good question but you will probably just have to set priority to port 443 traffic from that machine, and consider that 'good enough'. I don't know how to further isolate just the U1 traffic.

Comment: What router do you use?

Comment: WRT54G with Tomato firmware

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, it's a workaround. You can limit the up & download rate from the U1 app like this:

[image: U1 rate limiting]

This requires that you remember to switch this on and off for big files, but it should work.